# how to synchronize two directory?

Tags: mount, file-copy, synchronization

I want to using crontab to synchronize two directory between my linux partion and windows partion like this:

```
24 9 * * * cp -r /home/fan/Data /media/T/Data
```

But it would create a directory named Data in the origin Data directory, instead of copy the missing file from the source directory. I can't find a proper option at the cp manual to perfectly solve this. How can i copy the missing file(they do exist at the destination directory) from the src to dir.

And by the way, seems it need the T disk have been mounted to run the copy command, how to automatically mount the disk when i need to run the command(the mount command should run as root).

And how can i get the error message if the command have an exception?

Comment: `rsync` a chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the error-message portion of the question, you might choose to run a script from cron instead of the system command.

```
24 9 * * * /usr/local/sbin/sync_data.sh
```

Create the file as `/usr/local/sbin/sync_data.sh`, giving root ownership and execute permission: `chown root:root /usr/local/sbin/sync_data.sh && chmod 0700 /usr/local/sbin/sync_data.sh`. The contents of the script are below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "This script must be run as root." 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

# [ ] vs [[ ]] : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

dir_src="/home/fan/Data/"
dir_dst="/media/T/"

# A Boolean to know if running interactively or not
b_interactive=1
if [[ -v PS1 ]] ; then # The "-v PS1" method is for BASH 4.2+
    $b_interactive=0   # Could also use [[ -z "$PS1" ]]
fi

# Send messages to console or syslog.
function notify() {
    message="$1"
    if [[ $b_interactive -eq 1 ]] ; then
        echo "$message"
    else
        # eval combines args into a single string for execution...
        eval $cmd_logger -p err "$0: $message"
    fi
}

# If the mount point if not currently mounted...
if [[ "$(grep $dir_dst /proc/mounts)" = "" ]] ; then
    # Try to mount the directory.
    mount $dir_dst

    # Send a message to console or syslog.
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] ; then
        notify("$0 failed to mount $dir_dst")
        exit 1;
    fi
fi

# Create a backup directory if it does not exist
if [[ -d $dir_dst ]] ; then
    mkdir -p $dir_dst 2>/dev/null
fi

# A one-way sync to dir_dst, deleting files that no longer exist in DIR_SRC...
rsync -a --delete $dir_src $dir_dst &> /dev/null

# Check the return status of last command...
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    notify("$0: the rsync process succeeded.");
else
    notify("$0: the rsync process failed.");
fi

unset dir_src
unset dir_dst
unset b_interactive
```

Comment: Thanks. But i think the variable assignment should not with a "$"(like `DIR_SRC="/home/fan/Data/"` not `$DIR_SRC="/home/fan/Data/"`  ), and the test condition should be `[[ "$(grep  $DIR_DST /proc/mounts)" = "" ]]`, or it would report errors in my shell. But i can't check the status about `mount`. This `$(mount $DIR_DST)` would be `""` no matter it is success or fail. That really confused me.

Answer (score 7):

The go to tool for syncing data is `rsync`. You can sync either at the directory level or just the contents of a directory like so:

#### Examples

*directory sync*

```
24 9 * * * rsync -a /home/fan/Data /media/T/
```

*contents sync*

```
24 9 * * * rsync -a /home/fan/Data/ /media/T/Data/
```

The first example will sync the directory `Data` from `/home/fan` to the directory `/media/T`. The second example will sync the contents of `Data` to the directory `/media/T/Data`.

As an additional tip I'll sync to target directories using this notation:

```
24 9 * * * rsync -a /home/fan/Data/ /media/T/Data/.
```

The `/.` I find more obvious when reading through my `rsync` commands.

#### Behavior Examples

Using `rsync` is probably one of the most confused issues I deal with when training new users.

Sample data:

```
$ tree home/fan/Data/
home/fan/Data/
|-- file1
|-- file2
|-- file3
|-- file4
`-- file5
```

*1. syncing contents of dir Data*

```
$ rsync -a home/fan/Data/ media/T/
```

Notice we put the contents of `Data` into `T`.

```
$ tree media/T/
media/T/
|-- file1
|-- file2
|-- file3
|-- file4
`-- file5

0 directories, 5 files
```

*2. syncing the directory*

```
$ rsync -a home/fan/Data media/T/
```

Notice we put the directory `Data` into `T`.

```
$ tree media/T/
media/T/
`-- Data
    |-- file1
    |-- file2
    |-- file3
    |-- file4
    `-- file5

1 directory, 5 files
```

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' - thanks edited that in.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' `-a` implies `-p` which preserves all permissions including executability. What you can add is `-HAX`, which will preserve hard links, access control lists and extended attributes respectively.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' - graeme's correct, the man page says the -`a` includes `--perms` which would cover the execute bit. That's kind of what I thought, but had to check.

Comment: Yeah you're right, did a quick test.  Dunno why I've been using `-aE` all this time.  But hey, look: http://www.macinstruct.com/node/85 In fact a search for `rsync tutorial "-aE"` reveals this misinformation all over the place.

Comment: The `-H` one is can actually be a good idea on a root filesystem. I recently discovered that the `bzip2`, `bunzip` and `bzcat` binaries are all hard linked on my system - using `-H` would preserve things like this.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' - I use a much more elaborate `rsync` when copying data b/w EXT4 via NTFS mount SMB shares. Perhaps the `-aE` is a limitation of going to HFS+?

Comment: Could be. Those hits look mostly Mac oriented, and when I exclude the "-aE" I get other stuff.  So I must have picked it up cargo cult style.  Whenever I've looked at the man page, I've seen the list of switches `-a` includes and thought "Oh, those are various permissions but not `-E`..."

Answer (score 2):

Using `rsync`:

```
24 9 * * * rsync -a /home/fan/Data/ /media/T/Data
```

Add the extra `/` at the end of the name of the source directory will tell `rsync` to copy the contents rather than the full directory. `rsync` will also avoid copying files that have the same timestamps/size (ie ones that don't need to be copied in 99.99% of cases).

Also consider using the `--inplace` option for `rsync` to speed things up if you are syncing files on the same system. From the man page:

```
--inplace
    This option changes how rsync transfers a file when its data needs to be
    updated: instead of the default method of creating a new copy of the file and
    moving it into place when it is complete, rsync instead writes the updated
    data directly to the destination file.
```

There are pros and cons to this option though, probably the biggest con is that if the sync is interrupted, the target file will be left in an inconsistent state which can only be fixed by starting over again.

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir /office
mount /dev/xvdf /office
mkdir /home
mount /dev/xvdf1 /home

rsync -aHAXxSP /office /home
```

Comment: Hi Sumit, I've used the `{}` formatting tool to format your commands as code. Could you please explain why you've chosen those rsync options and how they address the problem posed by the OP?  Note also that the OP used /home/fan/Data /media/T/Data as source and destination directories. Using those in your answer would make it clearer. Thank you!